# Android Studio: Searchview for images, how?

Tags: java, android, image, search, android-studio

I have a Gridview with Images on it, and a search bar on the top of my page. I know how to use the search bar to filter text, but how can I filter images? Is there a way to somehow "tag" the images?

Thanks!

Comment: Are your images in your `xml` layout or are you getting them from db or net ?

Comment: @giannisf `public Integer[] mThumbsIds = {
                R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                R.drawable.ic_launcher
        };` That is how Im getting my Images. But the Images are displayed in a gridview.

Comment: You must create a data model for your images and use an `id` to filter them.

Comment: @giannisf How would I go about doing this? Can I use a query to filter the ids?

Comment: How would you like to `search` for images? With name?

Comment: @giannisf Yes, by using a searchview.

Comment: and you have a `ListView` with images ?

Comment: @giannisf No a `GridView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create a data model for your images and use an `id` to filter them.

```
public class MyDataModel {
    int resourceId;
    String imageName


    public MyDataModel(String name, resourceId);
    // constructors getters, setters, etc

}
```

And in your activity you can create a list with your data:

```
List<MyDataModel> data = new List();
data.add(new MyDataModel("name", R.drawable.name))
//import all your data
```

And then on your `SearchView` query listener add to filter to `Adapter`;

`adapter.getFilter().filter(//name);`

Comment: Where is the adapter created?

Comment: @Hudson You should create your own adapter. If you don't know how to do that then you should read, SO is not a code generation tool.

Comment: Ok, just trying to learn by example. Thanks for the answer and code.

Comment: What are the constructor getters and setters your talking about? That is the only part of the code I haven't figured out.

Comment: I am saying  that i am omiting uneccesary boilerplate code like declaring setters and getters

Comment: Yes but I have researched setters and getters but have found nothing. Do you know of a website or tutorial that would help me?

Comment: `public class MyDataModel{
public int resourceId;
public String imageName;

public MyDataModel(String imageName,int resourceId){
    // constructors getters, setters, etc
    this.imageName = imageName;
    this.resourceId = resourceId;
}
}` would this be what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of names of images and for each item of the adapter you tag the names of the images. Now filter the adapter using the tags of the images. :)